# How to pass arguments to batch file from VBScript using ShellExecute

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, windows-installer

I am using VBScript first time for one of my task. Trying to build a Windows installer.

Before importing everything into Application Folder wanted to try it out externally but things are not working. I want to perform the installation with elevated permissions. Please correct my script.

> Problem: If parameters sent to batch file contains spaces then the
>   parameters are truncated.

My VBScript code:

```
' Get target folder path from "CustomActionData" property.
dim targetDirectory
targetDirectory =  "D:\New folder\batch files\"

' Prepare file path of install batch file.
batchFilePath = targetDirectory & "install-v2.bat"

' Pass targetDirectory as argument to batch file.
' Run the install batch file with elevated permissions as administrator
Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
ObjShell.ShellExecute batchFilePath, targetDirectory, , "runas", 0
```

My Batch file:

```
@echo off

set HEADER=[MY-APP-NAME] %DATE% %TIME%
set TARGET_DIRECTORY=%1
set LOG_LOCATION="C:\Users\PureAjax\Downloads\batch-experiments\log.txt"

echo %HEADER% -- Instalation process started -- >> %LOG_LOCATION%
echo %HEADER% Target Directory %TARGET_DIRECTORY% >> %LOG_LOCATION%

rem will be using TARGET_DIRECTORY to achieve my task

echo %HEADER% -- Instalation process finished -- >> %LOG_LOCATION%
@pause
```

Log file

```
[MY-APP-NAME] 28-03-2020 23.07.15.78 -- Instalation process started -- 
[MY-APP-NAME] 28-03-2020 23.07.15.78 Target Directory D:\Newfolder\batchfiles\ 
[MY-APP-NAME] 28-03-2020 23.07.15.78 -- Instalation process finished -- 
[MY-APP-NAME] 28-03-2020 23.09.13.66 -- Instalation process started -- 
[MY-APP-NAME] 28-03-2020 23.09.13.66 Target Directory D:\New 
[MY-APP-NAME] 28-03-2020 23.09.13.66 -- Instalation process finished --
```

It can me seen in the log file that if path does not contain spaces then batch file receives the full path otherwise its truncated. **Alternatively**, Is there a way to pass arguments to batch file directly while building MSI installer?

Tried below solutions but they didn't work

1. `arguments =  Chr(34) & targetDirectory & Chr(34)` and the pass arguments to batch file
2. `ObjShell.ShellExecute "cmd", batchFilePath, arguments, "runas", 0`

Comment: Found couple of similar questions in stackoverflow but i am missing something.

Comment: also tried this ObjShell.ShellExecute "cscript", batchFilePath, arguments, "runas", 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bug which prevents using double quotes in parameters. 
You can try

```
ObjShell.ShellExecute "cmd",_ 
                      "/c """"" & batchFilePath & """ """ & targetDirectory & """""",,_
                      "runas", 0
```

where `%1` will be received with double quotes as `"D:\New folder\batch files\"`.

Alternatively, you can send the parameter with replaced spaces

```
p = Replace(targetDirectory, " ", "_") 
ObjShell.ShellExecute batchFilePath, p , , "runas", 0
```

and then replace it back in batch file

```
set TARGET_DIRECTORY=%1
set TARGET_DIRECTORY=%TARGET_DIRECTORY:_= %
```

Comment: if the directory contains _ (underscore) then they would get replaced with " "(empty space) right? This is undesirable behavior.

Comment: that is just an alternative way and you can use any character or a string, not only `_`

Comment: Ok. Checked the first half of your solution works for me. So accepted it. Thanks for your time.